# Debugging when all Links snap to origin

Tags: gazebo-6.5

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm wondering how I can debug my robot/code when the symptom is all links snapping to the origin. There are no error messages printed with --verbose.
I'm not sure whether it's a function of my SDF, or my code controlling it

[Here is the model](https://github.com/PeterMitrano/EKIPS_model/blob/master/model.sdf)

[Here is the code](https://github.com/PeterMitrano/EKIPS_code)

[the motor plugin I'm using is here](https://github.com/PeterMitrano/allwpilib/blob/master/simulation/frc_gazebo_plugins/dc_motor/src/dc_motor.cpp)

Although the code is WPILib code and probably won't make any sense to anyone.

If I just put in the model with no code running, it doesn't explode. I can drop it and move it all around and it works.
It seems to be something with my code or plugins, but I just don't know where to start.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12305/debugging-when-all-links-snap-to-origin/) by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 768 on 2016-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've uncovered the issue. It appears I was turning Java's NaN into a protobuf float64 message. This ended up translating to a force -2000 on some of the joints. Can anyone shed light onto why this would cause everything to snap the origin? Those are **large** but not **impossibly large** forces...?

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2016-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2016-01-11**:
it probably not that large at the beginning, but it might grow a lot in the proceeding simulation steps (you might be able to visualize this if you pause and then step into the simulation)

**Comment by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on 2016-01-13**:
Printing out the forces show it's truly only -2000.
Good suggestion with the stepping. Unfortunately, I can't pause it quickly enough...I've resolved the issue of ever sending NaN which is the real problem here

**Comment by [maaft](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2303/maaft/) on 2016-01-26**:
You can start the simulation paused. Just provide it with the "-u" option.